# Exporting Access Report to PDF -- unrecognized constant

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, pdf

I am developing a small VB.NET application which enables the user to export a report as PDF and save it to a specific location. The problem is that the `acFormatPDF` constant isn't recognized; the following code doesn't compile, with a red line under `acFormatPDF`:

```
Dim AP As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application
Dim dPath As String = "C:\"
Dim dReport As String = "Weekly_Schedule"

AP.OpenCurrentDatabase("H:\OvertimeRequest.accdb")
AP.DoCmd.OutputTo(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, dPath & "\" & dReport, True)
AP.DoCmd.CloseDatabase()
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Which version of Access are you using?

Comment: Should this have vb.net tag?

Comment: @QHarr This is obviously VB.NET, as VBA doesn't support `Try...Catch` blocks.

Comment: @CindyMeister The more relevant question is not _which version of Access are you using?_ (aside from it's being VB.NET, which means the OP is not using any version of Access), but rather _which version of Access do you have installed on your machine?_ or _which version of Access are you targeting?_

Comment: @ZevSpitz Hi! I can tell it is vb.net but I am wondering if the VBA tag should be changed or at the least the .Net added.

Answer (score 1):

`acFormatPDF` does not by default become a globally available constant in VB.NET (as it would be in VBA). You therefore should reference the full namespace: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Constants.acFormatPDF`.

Alternatively, you could add an `Imports` statement at the beginning of the file: `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access`; then you could use the `acFormatPDF` constant without the full namespace. This would allow you to simplify other code.

You can also add a global-level import at the project level, in the VB.NET project settings.

Since the value of this constant is the string `"PDF Format (*.pdf)"`, you could also pass in the string itself.

**Update**

Once you have an `Imports` statement, your code doesn't compile with a different error:

> BC30521   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OutputTo' is most specific for these arguments:
>
> > 'Sub OutputTo(ObjectType As AcOutputObjectType, [ObjectName As Object], [OutputFormat As Object], [OutputFile As Object], [AutoStart As Object], [TemplateFile As Object], [Encoding As Object])': Not most specific.
> >
> > 'Sub OutputTo(ObjectType As AcOutputObjectType, [ObjectName As Object], [OutputFormat As Object], [OutputFile As Object], [AutoStart As Object], [TemplateFile As Object], [Encoding As Object], [OutputQuality As AcExportQuality = acExportQualityPrint])': Not most specific.

If you look at the definition of the `DoCmd` type, you will see that there are two overloads defined for `OutputTo`; the VB.NET compiler has trouble choosing one over the other.

In order to resolve this, you can pass in a value for the last argument, which will force the use of the second overload; the default value for this argument is `AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint`. Either use positional arguments, using extra commas to force the value into the last argument:

```
AP.DoCmd.OutputTo(AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, "", Constants.acFormatPDF,
              dPath & "\" & dReport, True,,,
              AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint)
```

or named arguments:

```
AP.DoCmd.OutputTo(AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, "", Constants.acFormatPDF,
              dPath & "\" & dReport, True,
              OutputQuality:=AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint)
```

(Links [1](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?572410-RESOLVED-Access-Application-Object-not-allowing-OutputTo) and [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/364c5e28-f9ee-4054-862f-ff9e3866d2ba/referencing-the-office-2010-pias?forum=officegeneral))

Comment: Than you Zev Spitz! I really apreciate your help. I actually did figured out the .Constants.acFormatPFD. Unfortunately, if I do that then the “OutputTo” part becomes underlined!

Comment: @JCLD All that means is that there is something else wrong with the call to `OutputTo`, even when all the identifiers can be resolved. What error does it show you when you hover over the error?

Comment: this is the error i get: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OutputTo' is most specific for these arguments

Comment: @JCLD You really should ask a new question, as the problem you are now seeing is a different one than the current question. Until you do so, I will update my answer to resolve this issue as well. If you don't intend to ask a new question, I will ask and answer it myself.